# Consuming IIS-hosted WCF Service from Linux Web Application

Tags: c#, linux, wcf, web-services, iis

I was tasked at work to create a web application (**viewable in Firefox on Linux!**) that displays results in a tabular format using data exposed by a WCF service (written in C#) hosted on a separate Windows 7 machine on the same network.  Rather than returning formatted HTML, the WCF service returns structs and it will be up to the client application to take these objects, pull out the data, and format it.

Unfortunately, it has been a couple years since I have worked with any sort of web technologies.  **What is the best approach to solve this problem?  Is there anything more current than REST/AJAX/JSON/jQuery technologies?**  If anyone can point out some helpful and current resources on the proper way to accomplish this, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: You are using C# on linux? Is WCF available on Mono? Or any other soap frameowkr?

Comment: The WCF service was written in C#, but it is hosted in IIS on a Windows box.  The client web application is going to be run on a Linux box.  Development has not started yet on the client application, so it can be any language deemed fit.  I was purely trawling the community to see what the best choice would be for this client application.  C#/Mono, C++, Java/JavaScript, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SOAP framework to consume the WCF service. Configure WCF to use SOAP (one of the HTTP-bindings).

Webservices are easy to consume these days thanks to a standard RPC format (SOAP) and libraries supporting it. You can surely find a SOAP client for any language you are proficient in.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, as this is the general practice that should be followed.  For my specific solution, see my separate comment.

Answer (score 0):

Checking back in here to report my own solution for this problem.  I ended up going a bit of a different route that produced the simplest solution for the situation.  Instead of consuming any services on the Linux side, I simply made an ASP.NET website on the Windows/IIS side (where it is easy to consume the WCF services right from Visual Studio), and then just render the website on the Linux side via the URL in a Firefox browser.  For me, that fulfilled the customer requirements and was perfect, although this may not be the best approach for others that need to work with or manipulate the data in some way.